# having trouble with the view point of a jquery lightbox gallery on an FB iframe tab

Tags: jquery, lightbox, facebook-iframe, prettyphoto

i'm using prettyPhoto lightbox gallery in one of my FB iframe tabs and for some reason it behaves different than on the pages source. the problame is that the page is narrow and long, and the lightbox opens in the middle of the page insted of on the view point.
this problam occurs only on the FB iframe tab.

link to iframe tab : https://www.facebook.com/f2f.co.il/app_224451324266028

link to origin : http://fbstorage.co.il/f2f/portfolio/

would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem...

After hours, found that solution using the prettyphoto changepicture callback :

```
changepicturecallback: function(){
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
        function(info) {
            $(".pp_pic_holder").css('top', Math.max(parseInt(info.scrollTop) - parseInt(info.offsetTop), 0));
        }
    );
}
```

Regards.